# Website gets stop responding on a particular time

Tags: linux, bug, stoperror

I have a site running on shared hosting with the following configurations

> Apache Version  : 2.2.34
>
> PHP Version         :5.6.31
>
> MySQL Version   : 5.6.33-79.0
>
> Architecture    : x86_64
>
> Operating System : linux
>
> Perl Version    : 5.10.1
>
> Kernel Version  : 2.6.32-673.26.1.lve1.4.30.el6.x86_64

My site is get stopped automatically for some fraction of time interval everyday between 5:30 PM (IST) to 7:00 PM for.

It happens 2 to 3 times during this time elapse and than it start working as it is working for the whole day

I got stuck with this bug can anyone help?

Comment: As you are on shared hosting you should raise a ticket with your support.

Comment: They provided some IP visits on my site between that time, I blocked those IP's visits but the problem is still persists

Comment: If it's the whole web server that stops responding, it's their responsibility to get it working by checking MySQL slow query logs etc. If they face a definite problem doing that, their question would be on-topic here. Your best option really is to re-open the support ticket until the problem goes away, or move your hosting to a different provider.

Comment: when this problem occurs at that time of instance **`repair table`** query also get **`execution query time out error`**

Comment: Sometimes backups are freezing the site on shared (and not only) hosting. Ask your hosting provider to give you more info